# How to debug swift code on Android Studio for KMM?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

I can't set up breakpoints in Android Studio on my Swift code. I thought the KMM plugin allowed for this. Is there any way to achieve this?

How can I debug my iOS UI + shared business logic in iOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use https://github.com/touchlab/xcode-kotlin to debug shared code in Xcode